# Passing value from function to another class Kotlin

Tags: function, class, kotlin, parameter-passing

There is a calendar object which has day, month and year properties. Somebody has created a selectCurrentDay() member function that sets the object's properties to the current day. There is no need to type the date manually anymore because we have theselectCurrentDay() function!

Initially, the calendar shows a random date. Implement the current date printing: select it and print the day, the month and the year split by a space.

```kotlin
class Calendar(var day: String, var month: String, var year: String) {
    fun selectCurrentDay() {
        day = "13"
        month = "03"
        year = "2021"
    }
}

fun createCalendar() =
    Calendar("13", "03", "2021")

fun main() {
    val calendar = createCalendar()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Calendar(var day: String, var month: String, var year: String) {

    fun selectCurrentDay() {
        day = day
        month = month
        year = year
    }
}
fun createCalendar() = Calendar("13", "03", "2021")
fun main() {
    val calendar = createCalendar()
    val date: String = "day ${calendar.day}, month ${calendar.month}, year ${calendar.year}"
    println(date)
}
```

You can do something like this to print the values

Answer (score 0):

> First

```
import java.util.Calendar
```

I have 2 options for you

> 1

```
class Calendar(var day: String, var month: String, var year: String) {
    fun selectCurrentDay() {
        val calender = Calendar.getInstance()
        day = calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).toString()
        month = calender.get(Calendar.MONTH).toString()
        year = calender.get(Calendar.YEAR).toString()
    }
}
```

> 2 Create CurrentDateObject and make Calender class use current date by default

```
object CurrentDate {
    private val calender get() = Calendar.getInstance()
    val day get() = calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).toString()
    val month get() = calender.get(Calendar.MONTH).toString()
    val year get() = calender.get(Calendar.YEAR).toString()
}

class Calendar(var day: String = CurrentDate.day, 
               var month: String = CurrentDate.month, 
               var year: String = CurrentDate.year) {}
```